# SQL - Create complete matrix with all variables even if null

Tags: sql, matrix, reporting

please provide some assistance/guidance to solve the following:

I have 1 main table which indicates sales volumes by sales person per different product type.
Where a salesperson did not sell a particular product on a particular day, there is no record.
The intention is to create null value records for salesmen that did not sell a product on a specific day. The query must be dynamic as there are many more salesmen with sales over many days.

[image: Current table:]

[image: Target table:]

Thanks in advance

Comment: LEFT JOIN should help you a lot in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just generate records for all sales persons, days, and products using `cross join` and then bring in the existing data:

```
select p.salesperson, d.salesdate, st.salestype,
       coalesce(t.sales_volume, 0)
from (select distinct salesperson from t) p cross join
     (select distinct salesdate from t) d cross join
     (select distinct salestype from t) st left join
     t
     on t.salesperson = p.salesperson and
        t.salesdate = d.salesdate and
        t.salestype = st.salestype;
```

Note:  You may have other tables that have lists of sales people, dates, and types -- and those can be used instead of the `select distinct` queries.